# How to create a dynamic drop down list in html from values in database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I create a dynamic drop down list for my html page but use values from a database to populate the available drop down items in one box based on the value of another? It is identical to something where you select state from one drop down and in dropdown 2 there are the cities, you select city and you can select the zip codes from another.I have been searching on the net but I can not find anything that demonstrates using a database. Does anyone have some examples they can post? I am learning using the code below, I can add from a text box but nothing when pulling from a database? Does javascript actually have to make the connection and if so how do you protect the credentials to the dB?

```
function addCombo() {
    var textb = document.getElementById("txtCombo");
    var combo = document.getElementById("combo");

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = textb.value;
    option.value = textb.value;
    try {
        combo.add(option, null); //Standard 
    }catch(error) {
        combo.add(option); // IE only
    }
    textb.value = "";
}
```

Comment: AJAX is the way to go.

Comment: There are lots of questions on this.  Try searching for "cascading drop down".

Comment: First of all I think you have to understand in web devolopment what's on server side and what's on client side. Javascript (in this case) is on client side. Database and data fetching and arranging are on server side.

Comment: Also you might want to have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724342/ajax-form-update-second-select-when-choose-an-option-from-the-first-one). I did the same thing. Had some issues and got some help here at SO.

Comment: I understand but in the case of a dynamic drop down would this be considered server side or client side. The back end is php but when I see some other sites that do state to city and city to zip I can not get my head around how this is accomplished, just yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AJAX, check this example. The are 2 dropdowns.

- Services
- Doctors

So when you choose a service, then you can get the doctors. When you choose a doctor it redirects you to a URL. Hope it helps!

HTML
    
        Click to select a service
        Service 1
        Service 2
        Service 3

```
<select id="doctors">
</select>
```

JS

```
// The data that the service should return
// JSFiddle will echo it back for us on that URL
var doctors = {
    success: true,
    doctors: [
        {
            id: 71,
            name: "George"
        },
        {
            id: 72,
            name: "James"
        }
    ]
}

// This is what your JSON from PHP should look like
var jsonDoctors = JSON.stringify(doctors);
console.log(jsonDoctors);

// Bind change function to the select
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#services").change(onServiceChange);
});

function onServiceChange()
{
    var serviceId = jQuery(this).val();    

     $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            serviceId: serviceId,
            json: jsonDoctors // jsFiddle echos this back to us
        },
        success: onServicesRecieveSuccess,
        error: onServicesRecieveError
    });
}

function onServicesRecieveSuccess(data)
{
    // Target select that we add the states to
    var jTargetSelect = jQuery("#doctors");

    // Clear old states
    jTargetSelect.children().remove();

    // Add new states
    jQuery(data.doctors).each(function(){        
        jTargetSelect.append('<option value="'+this.id+'">'+this.name+'</option>');
    });
}

function onServicesRecieveError(data)
{
    alert("Could not get services. Please try again.");
}
```